# Pandas: Drop rows with missing data and apply binary encoding in UDF

Tags: python, pandas, user-defined-functions

In the middle of preprocessing data. I am binary encoding `t` and `f` values to `1` and `0`. Originally, this was my function:

```
def binary_encoding(df):
    encode = df.replace({"t":1, "f":0})
    return encode
```

This returns a float. I then changed the Encode line to

```
encode = df.replace({"t":1, "f":0}).astype(int)
```

but I get an error

```
ValueError: Cannot convert non-finite values (NA or inf) to integer
```

of the 4 columns I am binary encoding, 3 of which have 55 /18500 missing entries and have dtypes float64. The one other column was encoded successfully and is recognised as int64 and fully mapped as intended.

How do I write a function that drops the missing entries (which are blank inputs) and then applies the map originally set out?

Comment: A sample of your dataframe would be necessary. to give a more specific solution but something like `df.dropna().replace(....).astype(int)`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

#### To solve your ultimate goal of converting float values in columns with `NaN` to integers, you can use the [integer with N/A support](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/user_guide/integer_na.html) data type:

Suppose you have 4 columns as follows:

3 columns have `NaN` values and one column without.

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'Col1': ['f', 't', np.nan], 'Col2': [np.nan, 'f', 't'], 'Col3': ['f', np.nan, 't'], 'Col4': ['f', 't', 'f']})


  Col1 Col2 Col3 Col4
0    f  NaN    f    f
1    t    f  NaN    t
2  NaN    t    t    f
```

Now, after your binary encoding by your function:

```
def binary_encoding(df):
    return df.replace({"t":1, "f":0})

new_df = binary_encoding(df)

print(new_df)


   Col1  Col2  Col3  Col4
0   0.0   NaN   0.0     0
1   1.0   0.0   NaN     1
2   NaN   1.0   1.0     0
```

Data types of new_df:

```
new_df.dtypes

Col1    float64
Col2    float64
Col3    float64
Col4      int64
dtype: object
```

#### Data type conversion using the [integer with N/A support](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/user_guide/integer_na.html) data type:

```
new_df_int = new_df.astype('Int64')


print(new_df_int)


   Col1  Col2  Col3  Col4
0     0  <NA>     0     0
1     1     0  <NA>     1
2  <NA>     1     1     0
```

**Data types of new_df_int:**

```
new_df_int.dtypes

Col1    Int64
Col2    Int64
Col3    Int64
Col4    Int64
dtype: object
```

**You now have the integer data type and display as integers as you want!  You no longer need to drop the missing entries/rows now.**

You can also apply the data type conversion to individual columns instead of the whole dateframe, e.g.:

```
new_df['Col1'] = new_df['Col1'].astype('Int64')
```

Comment: TypeError: object cannot be converted to an IntegerDtype. Ive literally been stuck on this for 7 hours. Ive tried going through, removing rows when empty strings appear, to then attempting it once more but I cant quite seem to get the result im looking for. 

I can hard code it outside the function but I HAVE to write it up within. Quite frustrating but i really do appreciate the effort

Comment: @DropKick  Is your data only with numeric values or with string / characters ?  I seen you mentioned that you have 4 columns with 3 columns of float and one with int.  So, should be all numeric, right ?

Comment: df.dtypes: int64, object, float64.

The data contains strings, categoric data eg 't' 'f', and numeric in both int and float.

FYI: prices, addresses, names, ratings. Its Air BnB data if that gives you an idea. I am trying to covert 4 columns, 'host_is_superhost' etc, containing data 't' 'f'. 

I am close to throwing myself out the window lol

Comment: @DropKick  Can you just convert the columns of float type now ?  Those object type if they are strings or characters, can't convert to integer, as usual.

Comment: thats the problem I have now. So i just ```value_counts()``` on each column of interest, it only contains ```0.0s``` ```1.0s``` as expected. Theres no other incidences of anything else. The only thing I am aware of is that 55 entries are missing out of the 18500 rows. I will be running a regression model on this data later down the line. If I cant suss it out then ill leave it as floats (as i have been instructed to have int data for this mapping of categoric variabele). But i am now unsure if that will negatively impact the model.

Comment: @DropKick  So, if your data have only `0.0s` and `1.0s` and `NaN`, you should be able to use `.astype('Int64')`.   Try excluding the column with object dtype in applying `.astype('Int64')`

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/232973/discussion-between-dropkick-and-seabean).